# Libreoffice, how to copy from Writer and pasting unformatted in Calc, by default?

Tags: copy-paste, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

I have the revision of a translated text, made by the client, I am the third party reviewer and have to fill up an .xls module with all the source texts, the translated one, and the amended by the client.

*Right click > paste* brings up the same font (and size) it was in Writer, but I just need the pure text. We are talking about thousand or more entries, and 
*right click > paste special > unformatted text > OK* 
isn’t neither fast nor user friendly.

I found online only how to copy and paste within Calc in the way I want (using macros) but I didn’t manage to make it work across platforms. Is there any way please? It’s driving me crazy.

LibreOffice Version: 4.4.3.2, Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64 bit

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ideas at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1035/paste-unformatted-text-default-option/, but the only one that worked for me is a macro:

```vb
Sub paste_unformatted
    Dim document As Object
    Dim dispatcher As Object
    document = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    Dim args1(0) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args1(0).Name = "SelectedFormat"
    args1(0).Value = 1
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ClipboardFormatItems", "", 0, args1())
End Sub
```

Under `Tools -> Customize`, set a hotkey or a toolbar button for this macro.  For example, I used <kbd>F4</kbd>.

I tested this on Ubuntu, which should be similar to Mint.

Comment: Thanks @Jim K, I will have a look at this tomorrow, I’ve just closed the files because it’s time to go to bed here, 23:57! 
It would be nice if it was working with right click, paste…

Comment: There is currently no way to customize the context (right-click) menu.

Answer (score 0):

I copy paste @jim-k 's answer from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690806/shift-insert-for-pasting-unformatted-text-in-libreoffice) as that question might be deleted.
Go to `Tools -> Customize` and the `Keyboard` tab.  Under Functions, select `Edit` from the Category list and `Paste Unformatted Text` from the Function list.

This is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> by default.  Click `Delete` to clear this mapping.

Now, find <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> in the Shortcut Keys and click `Modify`.  Finally, press OK.

[image: paste unformatted]